# Python jmespath: How to return value inside nested dict if outer dict key matches criteria

Tags: python, json, jmespath

The data is

```
data_case_c = {
    "qualities": {
        "id": "0123456789",
        "key_criteria": "Target",
        "desired_value": {"id": "987654321", "label": "CORRECT"},
    }
}
```

I want check that `key_criteria` is `Target`. And if it is, return `qualities.desired_value.label`, which is `CORRECT` in this case.

Here is the query I thought might work

```
query = "qualities.key_criteria == 'Target' | qualities.desired_value.label"
```

It returns `None`.

The first half of the expression returns `True`.

```
query = "qualities.key_criteria == 'Target'"
```

How can I return the actual value of `qualities.desired_value.label` when a key on the same level as `desired_value` matches a specific criteria?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to filter, in JMESPath, you do need a JSON array, which you can achieve on an object with the [`to_array` function](https://jmespath.org/specification.html#to-array)

```
to_array(qualities)
```

Then you have to throw your [*filter projection*](https://jmespath.org/tutorial.html#filter-projections) in:

```
to_array(qualities)[?key_criteria == `Target`]
```

Select the attribute you want to query:

```
to_array(qualities)[?key_criteria == `Target`].desired_value.label
```

And finally, get rid of the array you created to be able to filter, with a [*pipe expression*](https://jmespath.org/tutorial.html#pipe-expressions):

```
to_array(qualities)[?key_criteria == `Target`].desired_value.label | [0]
```

And with all this, on your example JSON, you end up with:

```json
"CORRECT"
```

Comment: Ah, it needs to be an array. Thanks! That works